# How to search multiple names if present in a website?

Tags: search, google-search, search-engine

I was thinking if there is any way search in Google or other way to see multiple names or title if present in a website (although different web pages) and show list of pages found with targeted names? I know one way like:  `Jim Karon site:abc.com` but I need multiple name search at once.

Answer (score 1):

A query like `John Jack site:abc.com` will search the site abc.com and return the pages that contain the words "John" and "Jack".

If you want to be more specific, use `"John Smith" "Jack Brown" site:abc.com` - this will return results from abc.com that contain the exact phrase "John Smith" and "Jack Brown"

Source: [Google Advanced Search](https://www.google.com/advanced_search)